# Strapi too slow on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, strapi

I tried to deploy strapi on digital ocean $10 droplet (Ubuntu 18.04) with 2gb ram. My issue is that the admin panel is very slow to respond almost takes around like 5-10s for the login screen to show up.

I followed the official documentation in setting it up which is
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/digitalocean.html

My current strapi version is 3.0.5

I do not know what files are necessary for debugging since this is my first time setting up the server. I will be providing some of the files that I think will be necessary.

ecosystem.config.js

```
 GNU nano 2.9.3                 ecosystem.config.js

        DATABASE_PORT: '27017',
        DATABASE_NAME: 'vlancer', // DB name
        DATABASE_USERNAME: '', // your username for psql
        DATABASE_PASSWORD: '', // your password for psql
        PATH:process.env.PATH
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Edit: I just checked the http://128.199.25.147:1337/admin/main.be9bc0d5.chunk.js is taking about 1.9 minutes to fully download. The whole chunk is about 7mb. Is there any way to fix this?
[image]

Comment: It's a well-known issue with Strapi. When you create multiple relations on a document Strapi gets extremely slow, around 12s to get the response. I'm very disappointed with this behaviour of Strapi.

Comment: No I don't think that's the issue. It has something to with a very large payload being downloaded evertime I load up the admin panel for the first time.